# How to measure child to adult development quantitatively?

Tags: measurement, developmental-psychology

Are there any tests available that could quantify a personal development from child to adult if the development is more or less healthy and is not considered pathological?

I'm absolutely new to the psychology so the terminology could be wrong. What I'm looking for is to measure development features described in [the Wikipedia on Infantilism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infantilism) as:

> In a more general sense and in colloquial expressions - childlike behavior in adults, particularly lack of judgement and poor ability to make conclusions based on logical reasoning as well as actions driven more by immediate impressions and impulses rather than by rationale. Depending on degree of expression can range from mental disorder, to behavioral disorder or simply psychological makeup and personality trait of otherwise healthy person.